# Accounts With roles MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, roles

Im using the [alanning-roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) package, and a Meteor.method to create an account with roles, but the accounts gets created witout any roles.

The browser console throws `Internal 505 error` and the server console throws `invalid createUser Method.`

This is my method.

```
Meteor.methods({
 createUser:function(password,email,username){ //Normal Account
  var rol = "Normal",
       account = Accounts.createUser({
               email:email,
               password:password,
               username:username
          });
        console.log(account) //returns id wich i need to add the user to the rol
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(account, rol);
      return account;
   }
})
```

And calling it like i.e on an event handler.

```
Meteor.call('createUser',"example123","example@gmail.com","example",function(error,account){
 if(error){
   console.log(error.reason)
  }else{
   console.log("user created")
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Internal 505 error //this means something get wrong on the server, so the Meteor.call is ok.
```

Also the server method is ok, but you need to wrap the rol inside an array, like this.

```
var rol = ["Normal"]
```

The roles fields is like the email field on the `Accounts-Package`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, let me try it update: thanks ethan it works any reason why it should be an array and not an string?